# Using ROOM Dao - How I can get data of a table by comparing current date with date stored in table?

Tags: android, sql, android-room

I'm working on an activity which have 6 radio buttons which are(1-All, 2-Today, 3-Yesterday, 4-Last Week, 5-This Month, 6-Last Month) <=These are the names of the radio buttons.
So when I check the Today's radio button and press OK button, it should show me all entries which are inserted in database in today's date, and the reset of radio buttons should give me the result as there names are, as if I check Yesterday, it should give me the data that was stored yesterday.

The problem is I don't know the exact queries for this scenario which will give me the desired data.

I'm using ROOM database and in Dao class I've to write the queries which will give me data according to radio buttons.

There is a Date and Time column which stores the current date and time when the data is store in this table, so I have to match the date of table with the date of Today, Yesterday and so on, and according to that matching the data will be filter.

This is my Entity class(Table) from where I want to get data according to date.

```
@Entity
public class IncomeExpense  {
   @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
   private int id =0;

   private String type;
   private int amount;
   private String category;
   private String date;
   private String time;
   private String mode;
   private String note;
```

I just want someone who can write me Dao queries & functions which will give me filter data according to radio buttons.

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved this by using dates in string format. Like Standard format of dates `08-12-2015.` In Dao Class I used the following query to get the record for date. note that in my entity class date was also in String format.

```
@Query("SELECT * from scan_data where sqlDate = date('now') ")
List<Data> getTodayRecord();
```

For YesterDay Record

```
@Query("SELECT * from scan_data where sqlDate = date('now','-1 day')")
 List<Data> getYesterDayRecord();
```

For Last Week Record

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM scan_data WHERE DATE(sqlDate) >= DATE('now', 'weekday 0', '-7 days')  AND DATE(sqlDate) != DATE('now')  AND DATE(sqlDate) != DATE('now','-1 day')")
List<Data> getLastWeekRecord();
```

For Month Record

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM scan_data WHERE strftime('%W',sqlDate) != strftime('%W',date('now')) AND strftime('%Y',sqlDate) = strftime('%Y',date('now')) AND  strftime('%m',sqlDate) = strftime('%m',date('now')) AND DATE(sqlDate) != DATE('now', 'weekday 0', '-7 days')  AND DATE(sqlDate) != DATE('now')  AND DATE(sqlDate) != DATE('now','-1 day')")
List<Data> getLastMonthRecord();
```

Comment: Thanx for your support...I'll try this
would you please write me the query for getThisMonthRecord();
I'm fairly new in the programming

Comment: infact getLastMonthRecord() query works for every month including this month and previous months.

Comment: sqlDate is the name of the table's column..?

Comment: Yes it is the name of column

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning, I do `private String date` instead of `private Date date` later because of this I can't do the date filter as I want. So use `Date` data type `java.util.Date`